# Mouse in Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, mouse, x86-16

As part of a school project I am making a game that shows everything we've learned this semester.
So I made this game where you're this smiley guy and you run around a maze with obstacles that bring you back to the start of the maze and once you reach the end you go to the next level.

So I wanted to add a title screen with a "button" -- pretty much a title screen drawn in text and then:

```
 mov  ax, 3h
 int  33h
 mov  mouseClick, bx
 mov  mouseX, cx
 mov  mouseY, dx
 call checkMClick
 cmp  mousePos, 1h
 je   goodMPos
 jne  badMPos

 goodMPos:

 call firstLevel   
 call newMazePos
 call output

;---------------------------------------;                            

 checkMClick: cmp  mouseclick, 1h 
              je   checkMouseX
              jne  mouse  

 checkMouseX: cmp  mouseX, 7h
              jge  afterStartX
              jl   mouse

 afterStartX: cmp  mouseX, 23h
              jle  goodXPos
              jg   badMPos

 goodXPos:    mov  mousePos, 1h
              jmp  checkMouseY

 checkMouseY: cmp  mouseY, 7h
              jge  afterStartY
              jl   mouse

 afterStartY: cmp  mouseY, 11h
              jge  goodYPos
              jl   badMPos                 

 goodYPos:    mov  mousePos, 1h
              ret                 

 badMPos:     mov  mousePos, 0h
              jmp  mouse
```

But the coordinates for the mouse position are fucked up.

EDIT: [Here's the pastebin for the entire thing](http://pastebin.com/evsdLM6u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of the operands! The registers are the source.

```
mov  bx, mouseClick
mov  cx, mouseX
mov  dx, mouseY
```

Also function 3 of the mouse driver gives positions as if the screen were 640x200. You have to compensate for this.

Comment: I am in video mode `03h` which is 640x200 and 8x8 -- doesn't that mean that the coordinates should match the ones given by `int 33h`?

Answer (score 0):

```
; DATA segment
mouseClick DW ?
mouseX     DW ?
mouseY     DW ?
mousePos   DW ?

; CODE segment
mov  ax, 3h
int  33h
mov  [mouseClick], bx ; Write the value of BX to mouseClick
mov  [mouseX], cx     ; Write the value of CX to mouseX
mov  [mouseY], dx     ; Write the value of DX to mouseY
```

Those following instructions need to specify how many bytes we want to access.

```
cmp  mouseclick, 1h
mov  mousePos, 1h

cmp  WORD[mouseclick], 1h ; for to compare two bytes
mov  WORD[mousePos], 1h   ; for to write two bytes
```

And for to check unsigned nunbers if the value is above, or below, we can use the instructions: "ja, jna, jb, jnb". The instructions: "jg, jng, jl, jnl are for signed numbers.

In text modes, all coordinates are specified as multiples of the cell size, typically 8x16 or 8x8 pixels.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode

Comment: In text modes, all coordinates are specified as multiples of the cell size, typically 8x16 or 8x8 pixels. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode

I am in video mode `03h` which is 640x200 and 8x8 -- doesn't that mean that the coordinates should match the ones given by `int 33h`?

Comment: The mouse coordinates are between 640x200, but the textscreen is divided into 80x25 rows, columns.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I would have to multiply the X,Y accordingly?